# Primitive root modulo $n$

Tags: number-theory

**Definition 1:** Let $m>1$ and $(a,m)=1$. We call that $\delta$ is the *order* of $a$ if $\delta$ - minimal natural number such that $a^{\delta}\equiv 1 \pmod m$.

**Definition 2:** Number $g$ is called *primitive root* modulo $m$ if its order is $\varphi(m)$, where $\varphi$ - Euler function.

These definition are from Vinogradov's book (russian edition). But in some references I noticed that one requires that $g$ have to me coprime with $m$. Is it necessary or not?

Can anyone explain it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ g $ is not coprime with $ m $, then no power of $ g $ can be $ 1 $ modulo $ m $, so the condition is superfluous. Indeed, this is a consequence of the fact that a power of $ g $ is coprime with $ m $ if and only if $ g $ is coprime with $ m $, which follows from unique factorization in $ \mathbf Z $.

Comment: So if $(g,m)=d>1$ then for any $k$ we have that $g^k\not\equiv 1 \pmod m$. What means "superfluous" in this context?

Comment: Superflous means unneccisery

Comment: So if $g$ and $m$ are not coprime than definition of primitive root becomes pointless. So $g$ and $m$ have to be coprime. Right?

Comment: The definition of "primitive root", in itself, **requires** $ g $ and $ m $ to be coprime, in that it can never be satisfied otherwise. Asserting that they *also* have to be coprime is unnecessary for this reason.

Comment: Sorry for my English. $g$ and $m$ have to be coprime otherwise any degree of $g$ is NOT $\equiv 1 \pmod m$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.